# solidity split each number

Tags: solidity, remix

`uint number = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now))`
Split each number. For example, if the value of number is 1562, I need to be able to extract the result as: `uint a = 1, uint b = 5 , uint c = 6, uint d = 2.` 
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract extractDigits{
    uint8[] digits;

    function generateDigits() public returns(uint){
        delete digits;
        uint number = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now)));
        uint returnNum = number;
        while (number > 0) {
            uint8 digit = uint8(number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
            digits.push(digit);
        }

        return returnNum;
    }

    function getDigit(uint x) public view returns (uint8) {
        return digits[x];
    }
}
```

Basically we store the individual digits of a generated number into an array, where the ones place is at element 0, the tens place is at element 1, etc...

The `generateDigits()` first deletes any existing content in the array (you can handle this differently if you want to keep track of all digits generated over all time). Then it takes the generated number, and loops over it, extracting the last digit in the number (`number % 10`) and then removing that digit from the end (`number / 10`).

We store the extracted digit into the array of digits and repeat until there are no more digits left.

You can then retrieve the digits by querying the array as demonstrated in the `getDigit()` function.

Comment: Now this is the elaborate version of my "bare essentials" answer :)

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi why , Bro . why are you so cool?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with basic arithmetics. You'll find the `%` "remainder" (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#integers) operator useful.

Here's an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract Test { 
    function test() public pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 initial = 258;
        // as we are returning integers without decimal places it's always rounded down automatically
        return (initial % 10, initial % 100 / 10, initial % 1000 / 100);
    }
}
```